# mysql query return only the value that has not change over time

Tags: mysql

I have a table value like

```
Id_indicator,   Value ,   date_data
1               2        01/10/2016
1               2        03/10/2016
1               3        04/10/2016
1               2        05/10/2016
2              21        06/10/2016
2              21        07/10/2016
2              21        08/10/2016
3              3         09/10/2016
3              4         10/10/2016
3              4         11/10/2016
4              4         12/10/2016
```

I need to query that table and only need to get id_indicator and count(number or id_indicator)where value has not change over the time period.

I tried with group by query

```
select id_indicator, count(*), value  
from shrewd_db.indicator_status_history  
where  date_data between '2016-10-01 00:00:00' and '2016-10-01 10:59:59' 
group by id_indicator, value`;
```

now difficult to get only value that was unchanged like `id_indicator = 2`, `value =21` and `max (date_data) = 08/10/2016`

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1` isnt enough?

Comment: not really because it not giving me any output when I put count(*) = 1

Comment: Your sample data should use standard `yyyy/mm/dd` format

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: and your date in the sample data doesnt match the query date range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://rextester.com/LXFXN78174)**

I have to change the date range, otherwise only first row will be include it

```
SELECT `Id_indicator`, COUNT(*), max(value) as value
FROM Table1
WHERE  `date_data` between '2016-10-01 00:00:00' and '2016-10-13 10:59:59'
GROUP BY `Id_indicator`
HAVING max(value) = min(value)
```

**OUTPUT**

This result also will include indicator with only one record, where obviously cant change value. You may want add `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` to remove those

[image]

Comment: remember accept the answer as correct if solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly and you want all the counts where the `VAL` didn't change from record to record :

```
SELECT p.id_indicator,count(*) as cnt
FROM (
    SELECT t.id_indicator,
           t.value
           (SELECT s.value FROM YourTable s
            WHERE s.id_indicator = t.id_indicator 
              AND s.date_data between '2016-10-01 00:00:00' and '2016-10-01 10:59:59' 
              AND s.date_data < t.date_data
            ORDER BY s.date_data DESC
            LIMIT 1) as last_val
    FROM YourTable t
    WHERE t.date_data between '2016-10-01 00:00:00' and '2016-10-01 10:59:59' ) p
WHERE p.val = p.last_val
GROUP BY p.id_indicator;
```

If you want only those that in the entire period the `VAL` didn't change then it's easier:

```
select id_indicator, count(*),max(DATE_DATA) 
from shrewd_db.indicator_status_history  
where  date_data between '2016-10-01 00:00:00' and '2016-10-01 10:59:59' 
group by id_indicator
HAVING MAX(VALUE) = MIN(VALUE);
```

Comment: if your `group by id_indicator, value` wouldnt `max(value) = min(value)` for all groups?

Comment: thanks for your response but second query returning value that changed over the time

Comment: not really getting correct output what I was looking for like I need to get only id_indicator where value is same which is id_indicator 2 and it appears 3 time like and its value 21.

Comment: @Juan, data I have created as as sample but date format in my database is like 2016-10-01 00:00:00'

Comment: @Sumon But your data range `date_data between '2016-10-01 00:00:00' and '2016-10-01 10:59:59' ` will only match first row, isnt?

Comment: @Sumon Try the second query now, I accidently added `value` to the `GROUP BY` clause . Also, as Juan said, try to play with the date range which seems wrong .